# Copy specific row in the visible cells if condition is met in vba

Tags: excel, vba

My Problem is i am having one filtered excel file, in this file 1,2 columns are filtered based on another excel file, after filter the 2 columns 2 or 3 rows are visible, i am having one condition check the condition like this "text<100" if this text was found on the visible rows, copy specific columns of that particular row paste it into another sheet, text not found , take the another visible row copy some col like 3, 5,7 that particular row and paste it into another sheet, i tried one code but its not getting , it is copying all visible cells instead of that particular row.
can you please help me

```
Sub CopyPaste()

For i = 2 To 4

   b = Worksheets("Cheat Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim Filter As String
   Filter = Workbooks("Output file.xlsm").Sheets("Price Book").Range("A" & i).Value
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1 : $BA$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Filter
   
   c = Worksheets("Cheat Sheet").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim Split As String
   Dim Split1 As String
   
   Split = Workbooks("Output file.xlsm").Sheets("Price Book").Range("B" & i).Value
   Split1 = Right(Split, 2)
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1 : $BA$1000000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Split1
        
     'Autofill
    Worksheets("Cheat Sheet").Activate
    If InStr(Range("E" & i).Value, "<100") > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Windows("Output file.xlsm").Activate
        Worksheets("Macro").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("B:Z").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
       ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       Worksheets("Macro").Activate
       ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Start by putting the `Next i` after the `End If`

Comment: Why are you pasting code that does not compile? Post the actual code you are using.

Comment: @SJR I edit the code can you check once.